# EFCore "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')" if value is in environment variables

Tags: asp.net-core, environment-variables, connection-string, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

In an Asp.NET Core Web App, with EFCore-5, I have the following `ConfigureServices`

```
// ...
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

// get the connection string from secrets/env.variables
string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyWebApp"); /// <<< HERE
services.AddDbContext(connectionString);

services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();    
services.AddControllersWithViews();
// ...
```

and also `AddDbContext` extension method:

```
public static void AddDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,    /// <<< HERE
                providerOptions =>
                {
                    providerOptions
                        .EnableRetryOnFailure(
                            maxRetryCount: 5, 
                            maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                            errorNumbersToAdd: null)
                        .UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
                });
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
```

**If I put the connection string in `appsettings.Production.json` the site runs well, but once I remove it and put in EnvironmentVariables, the page gives me 500 error** and in the logs I have:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'connectionString')    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value,
> String parameterName)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder
> optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1
> sqlServerOptionsAction)

The error points to the line marked in the code above with second `HERE`.

I set the environment varialbes like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you doing anything different in `Program.cs` when creating the host builder? Have you tried closing VS and reopening after the env var was created? Environment is probably only loaded once and cached.

Comment: @DavidG, that is not about Visual Studio, that is in Production. In Production usually we have no Visual Studio that is a web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to make it work. My solution was to use the `SQLCONNSTR_MyWebApp` (as *System*, not *User* variable) and, **after** any change in the environment variables for the application, to take it into consideration execute `net stop was /y` followed by `net start w3svc` from a command prompt ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1#windows))

*Restarting IIS from IIS Manager **does not reload** properly the changes* in the environment variables...

Comment: You can follow the steps 3 and 4 of what I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67669514/net-core-secrets-on-a-production-server-when-not-hosting-on-azure/67694847#67694847)

Answer (score 1):

The default configuration loads environment variables and command line arguments prefixed with `DOTNET_` and `ASPNETCORE_`.

Based on that, you should use

`ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings__MyWebApp` or `ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings:MyWebApp`

Is possible to configure a custom prefix with `AddEnvironmentVariables`:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "MyCustomPrefix_");
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```