# Use Azure Key Vault from external web app

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-keyvault

is it possible to use Azure Key Vault for web app, which is hosted somewhere else? I'm looking for the most cost-effective way, how to do that, so ideally I would like to use really just the Key Vault. I can allow external IP in *Key vault -> Networking*, but I don't see any possibilities how to set up access policy for external web app in the *Key vault -> Access Policies*.

Any experiences or ideas how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need KeyVault if what you're trying to  do is just securing some secrets for your OnPremise applications. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67669514/net-core-secrets-on-a-production-server-when-not-hosting-on-azure/67694847#67694847)

Answer (score 4):

> but I don't see any possibilities how to set up access policy for
> external web app in the Key vault -> Access Policies.

One possible way to accomplish this would be to create a Service Principal in your Azure AD and give it access to your Key Vault (under Access Policies). Then you would use this Service Principal in your "external" web app to connect to the Key Vault.

Comment: This is the correct and only way to accomplish this task.  A Key Vault requires either a User or Service Principal in order to get a token for the access policy.  You can't use any external credentials.